# SQL agent Job - How to schedule a job to run for first 2 weeks of January every year

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I am trying to create a schedule in SQL agent job (which executes a SSIS package) so that it can run for first 2 weeks of January every year. But there is no closest option I can find. So I created a daily schedule and tried to customize the schedule by adding a job step which has Transact SQL query. This query will check the date and month.If the month is January and date is within 14th Jan, then it execute the SSIS package. If not, an error will be raised using "RaiseError"  and the job with fail. But, instead of this workaround, is there any way to do it in the schedules itself?

Answer (score 0):

You could merge these two steps together if you think this would be little bit easier.

The way you could do is either one of this (All done in SSIS):

1. Add a expression in the precedence constraint to check the date, if it meets the condition, then go forward, it is better to set `expression and constraint`
2. Add a container to group all the tasks, set the check date expression to `DISABLE` expression from the properties page, if it does NOT meet the condition, then disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have considered that too. But my end user don't want this job to run daily.  They just want to schedule it only for first 2 weeks of January every year